# Storing Integers in an Char Array in C

Tags: c, arrays

Im doing some work for Uni and wrote a programm which stores Integers in an char Array and converts them to their ASCII Values and prints them at the end. My code did not work before and only started working when i changed "%c" to "%i" in my scanf line. My question: Why does it have to be "%i" when i wanna store those Numbers in an char Array and not an Int Array. Thanks!

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i; /counter
    char numbers[12];
    printf("Please enter 12 Numbers\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        printf("please enter the  %i. Number\n", i+1);
        scanf("%i", &numbers[i]);// <-- changed "%c" to "%i" and it worked.why?

    }
    for(i = 0; i < 12;i++){
        printf("The %i.ASCII value is %i and has the Char %c\n", i+1, numbers[i], numbers[i]);
    }




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior. `%i` is for `int` but you try to read a `char`. Have you tried `%hhi`?

Comment: Please post a sample of input used and output desired.

Comment: They probably expect you to read the number through %d or %i into an `int`, then convert that `int` to a `char`. Not store it in the `char` directly with %hhi, because then scanf handles the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

`%c` is for reading a single character. So for example if you type in `"123"`, `scanf` will read `'1'` into the `char` variable and leaves the rest in the buffer.

On the other side `%i` is the specifier for `int` and will therefore lead to undefined behavior when trying to read in a `char`.

I think what you are looking for is the `%hhi` specifier, which reads a number into a `char` variable.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! Never heard of %hhi in my lectures, so basically the prof probably wanted the %i method but %hhi works just fine!!

Comment: @informatiker Normaly the teacher wants you to read the spec for functions you are using. ;)